# NPM : Warning: a promise was created in a handler at ... but was not returned from it

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, bluebird

I use Node.Js 8.10.0 and npm 5.8.0.
Nearly everytime i tried to install a module via "node -install", i got a huge list of errors :

```
(node:44148) Warning: a promise was created in a handler at C:\Users\Cedric\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\tarball.js:39:25 but was not returned from it, see ...
at ret (eval at makeNodePromisifiedEval (C:\Users\Cedric\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promisify.js:184:12), <anonymous>:8:21)
(node:44148) Warning: a promise was created in a handler at C:\Users\Cedric\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\tarball.js:39:25 but was not returned from it, see  ...
at ret (eval at makeNodePromisifiedEval (C:\Users\Cedric\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promisify.js:184:12), <anonymous>:8:21)
...
```

It seems to have a problem with "pacote" ou "bluebird" module.
I look at the dependecies :

```
+-- npm@5.8.0
| +-- bin-links@1.1.0
| | `-- bluebird@3.5.1  deduped
| +-- bluebird@3.5.1
| +-- cacache@10.0.4
| | `-- bluebird@3.5.1  deduped
| +-+ libcipm@1.6.0
| | |-- bluebird@3.5.1  deduped
| | `-- pacote@7.6.1  deduped
| `-- pacote@7.6.1
|   `-- bluebird@3.5.1  deduped
`-- npm-check-updates@2.14.1
  `-- bluebird@3.5.1
```

I also tried to create a new project via angular CLI, i got the same type of errors, plus some new ones :

```
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Cedric\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-26T15_11_58_332Z-debug.log
Error: Package install failed, see above.
Package install failed, see above.
```

End of log file :

```
17550 silly tarball trying pac-proxy-agent@1 by hash: sha512-QBELCWyLYPgE2Gj+4wUEiMscHrQ8nRPBzYItQNOHWavwBt25ohZHQC4qnd5IszdVVrFbLsQ+dPkm6eqdjJAmwQ==
17551 silly tarball no local data for proxy-agent@~2.0.0. Extracting by manifest.
17552 verbose stack Error: write after end
17552 verbose stack     at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:236:12)
17552 verbose stack     at PassThrough.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:287:5)
17552 verbose stack     at PassThrough.Writable.end (_stream_writable.js:563:10)
17552 verbose stack     at ReadEntry.entry.on (C:\Users\Cedric\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\extract-stream.js:19:41)
17552 verbose stack     at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
17552 verbose stack     at ReadEntry.emit (events.js:211:7)
17552 verbose stack     at ReadEntry.emit (C:\Users\Cedric\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\node_modules\minipass\index.js:287:25)
17552 verbose stack     at ReadEntry.[maybeEmitEnd] (C:\Users\Cedric\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\node_modules\minipass\index.js:240:12)
17552 verbose stack     at ReadEntry.end (C:\Users\Cedric\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\node_modules\minipass\index.js:153:27)
17552 verbose stack     at Unpack.[consumeBody] (C:\Users\Cedric\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\lib\parse.js:210:13)
17552 verbose stack     at Unpack.[consumeChunkSub] (C:\Users\Cedric\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\lib\parse.js:391:40)
17552 verbose stack     at Unpack.[consumeChunk] (C:\Users\Cedric\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\lib\parse.js:362:30)
17552 verbose stack     at Unzip.(anonymous function).on.chunk (C:\Users\Cedric\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\lib\parse.js:291:59)
17552 verbose stack     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
17552 verbose stack     at Unzip.emit (events.js:211:7)
17552 verbose stack     at Unzip.emit (C:\Users\Cedric\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\node_modules\minipass\index.js:287:25)
17553 verbose cwd D:\angular-expert\ngviacli
17554 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.16299
17555 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Cedric\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--quiet"
17556 verbose node v8.10.0
17557 verbose npm  v5.8.0
17558 error write after end
17559 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Don't know if this last error is linked to the other but it seem to be also related to tarball archive.

Any idea to resolve those issues ?

Comment: To be clear: these aren't errors; they're warnings. I came here in search of a solution because they're annoying but the good news is that, as far as I know, npm isn't breaking because of those Warnings. I'm able to run npm install without issue even though I get tons of these promise warnings. Bluebird's explanation of the warning is here: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/docs/docs/warning-explanations.md#warning-a-promise-was-created-in-a-handler-but-was-not-returned-from-it